# Read tail by partition from CSV file with dask.dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, dask

With Dash we can easily read CSV files and take first lines with `head`, even in multiple partitions.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('data.csv').head(n=100, npartitions=2)
```

But I would like to read last lines of my CSV file on multiple partitions, something like this :

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('data.csv').tail(n=100, npartitions=2)
```

Dask data.frame doesn't seem to support partition on `tail` method.

In `pandas` I could manage it with `skiprows`, but this options seems not available in `Dask`.

Comment: Since this task is not memory-heavy (and so doesn't require `dask`), why not use `pandas` ?

Comment: My pipeline use essentially ```dask``` but it could be an option even if I read millions of lines (I have a huge csv file...).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have answered your own question.  The tail method exists

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('data.csv').tail(n=100)
```

See the [Dataframe API](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html)

Comment: Sorry I edit my post, the problem with the ```tail``` implementation of ```dask``` is that according documentation "Caveat, the only checks the last n rows of the last partition.". So I can only use the last partition, I would like to use more than 1 partition.

Comment: Nope, that it not currently supported.  You'll have to raise an issue, or better yet, provide a fix with a pull request.

Comment: Ok thanks, for the answer ! Not sure to be able to provide a pull request but I'll give a look.